# Please ID succulents and their hardiness zone to survive winter

Tags: succulents, plant-hardiness

[image: Succulent arrangement]
[image: succulent I]

I need help please to ID these succulents and their hardiness zone. I'd like to know if they will survive where I live, in zone 5, if left outdoor in the winter while keeping them in their current container and arrangement. It's only plant H that I've seen survived a zone 5. I've asked all this information from the big-box store where I bought them from, but no one seem to know the answers.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: These are Sedum and Sempervivum. Both genus are also alpine, and similar species to yours growths in alpine level. But before to be sure, we need a precise identification.  "Zone 5" so are you in US./Canada? If you are in Europe, I could try to identify the genus.

Comment: Please ask each individual plant in separate questions.