# What is the yellow-green succulent with red tips in this succulent group?

Tags: identification, succulents

Could you please ID succulent A (and G) in the following picture? Succulents A and G look the same species to me - aren't they? What is its hardiness zone? Would it survive the coldness of zone 5, if left outdoor in the winter, while keeping it in its current container and arrangement?

[image: Succulent arrangement]

This question is based on [another (closed) question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35386/please-id-succulents-and-their-hardiness-zone-to-survive-winter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and G seem to be [Sedum rupestre 'Angelina'](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=c655).

Not all the time throughout a year it has such nice color, but it is evergreen in temperate zones, and it is an excellent ground cover, once established.

According to the internet, it will survive in zone 5!

[image]

(photo via [budgetplants.com](http://budgetplants.com))