# What is the rope-like succulent in this succulent group?

Tags: identification, succulents

Could you please ID succulent B in the following picture? I know it is a little smallish, but I don't have better picture. What is its hardiness zone? Would it survive the coldness of zone 5, if left outdoor in the winter, while keeping it in its current container and arrangement?

[image: Succulent arrangement]

This question is based on [another (closed) question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35386/please-id-succulents-and-their-hardiness-zone-to-survive-winter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it is *Sedum dasyphyllum*, because of leaves. Also this should survive outside.