# What is the spiky red-tinged succulent in this succulent group?

Tags: identification, succulents

Could you please ID succulent C in the following picture? I like its reddish color. What is its hardiness zone? Would it survive the coldness of zone 5, if left outdoor in the winter, while keeping it in its current container and arrangement?

[image: Succulent arrangement]

This question is based on [another (closed) question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35386/please-id-succulents-and-their-hardiness-zone-to-survive-winter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet for *Sedum album*. It is a Sedum, but there are many species with similar look.  Yes, it should survive outside.