# What is the turquoise-green succulent in this succulent group?

Tags: identification, succulents

Could you please ID succulent E in the following picture? I am impressed by its blue color and gentle habit. What is its hardiness zone? Would it survive the coldness of zone 5, if left outdoor in the winter, while keeping it in its current container and arrangement?

[image: Succulent arrangement]

This question is based on [another (closed) question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35386/please-id-succulents-and-their-hardiness-zone-to-survive-winter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a Corsican Stonecrop (Sedum dasyphyllum) or one of its hybrids - could be Blue Tears. Hardy to at least Zone 3 in the US; definitely fine where you are, Vivid. http://www.sedumphotos.net/v/sedum-def/Sedum+dasyphyllum+pubescent+form.jpg.html