# What is the flower-like succulent in this succulent group?

Tags: identification, succulents

Could you please ID succulent F in the following picture? It looks like a flower, and is similar to D. What is its hardiness zone? Would it survive the coldness of zone 5, if left outdoor in the winter, while keeping it in its current container and arrangement?

[image: Succulent arrangement]

This question is based on [another (closed) question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35386/please-id-succulents-and-their-hardiness-zone-to-survive-winter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plant F appears to be one of the Echeverias (E. Holy Gate pictured here as an example https://mountaincrestgardens.com/echeveria-holy-gate/). There are hundreds of different ones, and I'm not entirely sure which variety it is, but they are hardy only down to 20deg F, or Zone 9.

Plant D is more likely a Sempervivum or houseleek variety such as Purple Beauty, hardy in your zone https://www.calgaryplants.com/products/sempervivum-purple-hens-and-chicks

Comment: I disagree that it is E. Holy Gate since yours is missing the red coloring on the spine.  My guess is it's Echeveria Blue Star or Echeveria Colorata it comes down to the true shape of the leaves, which is hard to tell from this angle.  Echeveria, with approximately 180 species, are native to mid to higher elevations in the Americas. Echeverias produce offsets which can be divided from the main plant and potted up. They will root readily.