# What is the succulent with small opposite red-tipped leaves in this succulent group?

Tags: identification, succulents

Could you please identify succulent H in the following picture? It has really nice red tones, and I like its shape. What is its hardiness zone? Would it survive the coldness of zone 5, if left outdoors in the winter, while keeping it in its current container and arrangement?

[image: Succulent arrangement]

This question is based on [another (closed) question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35386/please-id-succulents-and-their-hardiness-zone-to-survive-winter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Aeonium, it's a Sedum, common name stonecrop. There are hundreds of varieties; most are hardy down to Zone 3, so long as they're not too wet in winter. This one might be Sedum spurium Red Carpet http://www.midwestgroundcovers.com/plant/Sedum-spurium-Red-Carpet but there are many very similar varieties. The redness of the leaves varies according to the time of year, most often being a deeper red in winter.

Comment: "Red Carpet" truly looks like the one in the photo.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Red [Aeonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeonium)

citing from wikipedia:

> Aeonium (tree houseleek) is a genus of about 35 species of succulent,
>   subtropical plants of the family Crassulaceae. Many species are
>   popular in horticulture. The genus name comes from the ancient Greek
>   "aionos" (ageless). While most of them are native to the Canary
>   Islands, some are found in Madeira, Morocco, and in East Africa (for
>   example in the Semien Mountains of Ethiopia).

It´s definately a Aeonium, also **F** is one too. I believe H is *Aeonium Cyclops*

Its hardiness zone is 10 - 15 it can survive indoors in colder locations. My grandmother have them outside in a 8b zone and they do fine on winter, but on a 5 zone I don´t think they will